# How to associate color with accuracy for segmented gauge?

Tags: interaction-design, interface, info-visualisation, iphone, gauge

I'm writing a personality test app and am thinking of a way to implement the UI for recording answers. The test requires the user to answer how accurately terms like "kind" or "cold" describe their personality, using the following scale:

- 1 - Extremely Inaccurate
- 2 - Very Inaccurate
- 3 - Moderately Inaccurate
- 4 - Slightly inaccurate
- 5 - Neither accurate nor inaccurate
- 6 - Slightly accurate
- 7 - Moderately accurate
- 8 - Very accurate
- 9 - Extremely accurate

I want to simplify the process of recording answers using a gauge, but there's not enough space to provide description of all answers. So I'm thinking of using a color-coded gauge with 2 poles - not accurate and accurate.

**How can I use color gradation to indicate that one side of the gauge is accurate while the other is extremely inaccurate?**

Is there a better way to condense the above 9 point answer scale into a color coded gauge?

[image]

Comment: The issue is that we are used to having positive on the right and negative on the left, just like in math with the axis. May i ask, why does it have to be the other way around with the Woman?

Comment: Setting aside the fact that you should never use colour alone as your main indicator for anything (here's a useful resource for that: http://blog.usabilla.com/how-to-design-for-color-blindness/). Do you actually need to show the user each of those graduations? Could you just offer a slider with marked end and centre values and let the user deal with the rest? I suspect user testing will reveal that the nuances of your 9-point scale will be left unused in favour of more polarised 'yes', 'no', 'maybe' type answers.

Comment: @UXLabs Yeah, this would make sense. This is a pre-built gauge that only goes clockwise. There's some pretty sophisticated calculations that I need to inverse to make it go counter clockwise.

Comment: @AlexStone You shouldn't need 'sophisticated calculations' to reverse the gauge (assuming that you already have some math to make the pointer go where you want it) - Relabel the markings in reverse then you only need the following math: (top-of-range - value) + bottom-of-range = reversed-value. In your case (9 - V) + 1 = rV. For example to show 9: (9-9)+1=1 - pointer appears in the current 1 position (relabelled as "9"). To show 5: (9-5)+1=5 - pointer appears in the current 5 position. And to show 1: (9-1)+1=9 - pointer appears in the 9 position (relabelled as "1")

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a case where the use of icons might be better than encoding the details using colours. I think because you are dealing with opinions that people give about themselves in a specific context, it is also questionable how accurate the responses recorded might be.

Nevertheless, if I wanted to represent this in a visual way (in combination with colours to make it clearer), I would probably use a BLUE --> RED scale where red would represent inaccurate (using the analogy of an error mistake associated with the colour) as RED/GREEN could create an issue for accessibility.

Here's a example for your reference:

[image]